# Scientific notation not working in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, format, scientific-notation

I am using python version `3.9.5`, and trying to use scientific notation using the `format` method, but it's not working!

I have searched across the web for this, but didn't get anything.

I used the formatting method of `format(num, f'.{precision}e')` to turn it into scientific notation, and it works for non-decimal numbers, but when I use decimal numbers, it doesn't work:

```py
num = int(10**9) # 1000000000
dec = int(10**-4) # 0.0001

print(format(num, '.5e'))
print(format(dec, '.5e'))

# 1.00000e+09
# 0.00000e+00
```

As you can see, the second output is meant to be a different result but I got `0.00000e+00`

---

Can somebody please help me solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand that `int(x)` will always be an integer?  Try this:  `int(10**-4) == 0`.  It's `True`.  The assignment to `dec` is equivalent to `dec = 0`.

Comment: you are casting the value to `int()` but that cast here on the second value casts to `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int(x)` will always be an integer.

```
print(int(10**-4))

#output 
0
```

you need to do:

```
print(format(float(10**-4), '.5e'))

#output
1.00000e-04
```